# Table cell height is not maintained on page break

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing

I'm having a dynamic table rendered on a PDF using the plugin dompdf.
I'm trying to give every cell in this table a constant height with CSS styles:

```
.shipment td {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    height: 28px;
}
```

The problem with this is that the cells contained in the first page get the correct height, but every cell shown from the second page on gets its height reset to the default value.

Here is a little example of the table: https://jsfiddle.net/4axc4L56/

Is there a way to have the height I want to set for all the cells in every page?

Comment: Try adding a 'wrapper' class to the table element and then set the height with '.wrapper td' ? Let me know if that works.

Comment: @MightyRevenge same thing happens! Works for the first page but not for the others.